# Creating a profile in the database once an user is registered, working with IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently making a forum using ASP.NET and I'm trying out to generate a profile entry in the database once the user makes an account (I have a '*Profile*' model with a foreign key to '*ApplicationUserId*' deriving IdentityUser).

Though, I have used scaffolding on *ApplicationUser* and most of the generated code that manages user registration uses async functions located in `Register.cshtml.cs` and I don't thoroughly comprehend how they interact with the database. My method of creating a profile would've been to get the context of my database through

`IServiceProvider.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()`

then created a Profile object with `New Profile()` and lastly added it to the database that way. Though that beats me because I don't know how to obtain the serviceProvider used to fetch the database context, inside the `Register.cshtml.cs` file.

Sorry for my poor understanding of .net, the documentation is overwhelming for me since I'm a beginner.

**Phrased in another way, my question boils down to, how can I create an instance of a profile and add it to my database, when most of the user registration (to my understanding) uses pre-defined functions by the framework?**

(Part of) register.cshtml.cs, in case I should include it

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await setDataAndCountsAsync(user);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: So, you want to create a user without a user setting up an account? Or is there a problem with using what you have in the boilerplate?

Comment: @RyanWilson Once an user creates an account, I want to associate his account with a profile, where he can set up an avatar, a description, a title, that he can edit

Comment: So what is the issue? You haven't explained that very well. Is the profile something custom or built in asp.net?

Comment: @RyanWilson It's something custom, a model I created. My question was how exactly would I tackle adding a profile to the database when I don't have the context of the database, or if there's an alternative method of doing so

Comment: Is the user supposed to setup this profile themselves? If so, you can use the `UserManager`  to get values you need related to the user account for the profile. [microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, any user can edit their profile. honestly all I want is that once an user has registered an account, a Profile entry gets added to the Profile table in the database, and the only data it contains is the ApplicationUserId foreign key, so I can use it in the controller

Comment: You are already getting this foreign key at this line of the boilerplate: `var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);`, just modify it to add this `userId` (foreign key) into your profile table at that point in time. Before it sends them to verify their email or redirects them if they already verified it.

Comment: @RyanWilson sorry, as a last question since this'd been my primary concern all along, how exactly do I insert data into the profile table in the database, since I don't have an instance of its context in this file?

Comment: Modify the constructor of the controller to inject your db context. Then use it where needed. These boilerplate's are setup as a template, you can modify it as necessary. Of course you'll need to ensure your db context is registered in the service container inside of `Startup.cs` pre dotnet 6 or in `Program.cs` in dotnet 6+

Comment: So how do you create the Profile? Could you pls share your code? Why not have the DbContext for you said here:`I don't have the context of the database`?

Comment: @Rena Solved this, I didn't know I can inject the database even into the class asp.net generated for me when I scaffolded for the user registration functionalities. thank you though.